# Import specific types with alias in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I can import specifc types as

```
import { Type1, Type2 } from '../../my-file';
```

I can import all types from a file with alias as

```
import * as fromApp from '../../../store/app.reducers';
```

How can I import specific types with alias, something like

```
import { Type1, Type2 } as MyTypes from '../../my-file'; // of-course, this does not work
```

Comment: So what is the final usage of types do you think? If you are looking for `MyTypes.Type1` or `MyTypes.Type2`, you can use `import * as MyTypes` statement.

Comment: But in the case there is an unneeded `Type3`, should be great to define an alias for `Type1` and `Type2` only.

Comment: you know that requiring less types doesn't change anything for build process just go with `* as Whatever` that is if you are talking just about types

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can do:

```
import {Type1, Type2} from '../../my-file';

const MyTypes = {Type1, Type2};
```